# Questions about Catmull-Clark

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I have a few questions regarding the algorithm

1) Can the input mesh be anything (i.e, triangle mesh, hexagonal mesh) ? According to this [website](http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2008/08/01/catmull-clark-subdivision-the-basics/), Catmull-Clark works for arbitrary polygon meshes:

> The paper describes the mathematics behind the rules for meshes with quads only, and then goes on to generalize this without proof for meshes with arbitrary polygons.

However, I have only seen it used in the context of quads.  For example, edgepoints are calculated using two facepoints and the original endpoints.  I can envisage scenarios where, in a non-quadrilateral mesh, there will be more than two facepoints.

2)  Assuming (1) is true, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface), it says:

> The new mesh will consist only of quadrilaterals, which in general will not be planar. The new mesh will generally look smoother than the old mesh.

Does this mean that if I put in a triangle or hexagonal mesh, the result will be a quadrilateral mesh?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure. Why didn't you believe the website?
2. Yes. Every face produced by Catmull-Clark will have one corner from the original face, two corners at edge points, and one corner at the face point; and will hence be a quadrilateral.